# Azure Storage Emulator in C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

i am trying to use storage emulator with C#, I downloaded sample application from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started/):

But i can't run that app, what are the steps i need to carry out to run that app successfully? do i need to init my storage emulator first? or do i need to pass any connection string?

I installed sample console application from above link, then initialized and started my storage emulator, and then I run above application, I got following inner exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Consider editing that into the question, since not everyone reads comments before moving on.

Comment: What version of  storage eumulator are you using? Which line of code get the exception? I download the demo code. It works correctly on my side. I use the storage enmulator version 5.2. More info about Azure storage emulator, please refer to this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)

Comment: I am using 4.0 version of azure storage emulator...and after calling await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(requestOptions, null) method it is going in catch part and throwing bad request exception.